# How can I play DirectX 10 games with an HD6450 video card?

Tags: wine, steam, radeon, gpu-driver

My question would be about video card compatibility with DirectX 10. I wanted to play a game (Star Trek Online) with Steam, but after loading it says my Radeon HD6450 2 GB video card is not compatible. Meanwhile with Windows it does work. Thanks for any helpful suggestions.

[image: screenshot showing Unsupported DirectX Version message box]

The message says:

> #### Unsupported DirectX Version
>
> Support for the Video Card you are using has ended. You will be unable
> to play using this Video Card. Please upgrade your Video Card to one
> that supports DirectX Hardware Feature Level 10.0 or higher; See you
> Video Card manufacturer's documentation for information on DirectX
> Hardware Feature Level support.

Comment: You may find useful information about Steam Play compatibility for this game here: https://www.protondb.com/app/9900

Answer (score -1):

AMD's 32-bit Ubuntu drivers [are found here](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_i386_UB_14.01.deb) and 64-bit Ubuntu drivers [are found here](https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/fglrx_15.201-0ubuntu1_amd64_UB_14.01.deb).  Sadly, AMD has not kept up with the times and those are v14 drivers, last updated four (4) years ago, for an eight year old card design.

Therefore, I would recommend making sure the old AMD drivers are removed, and using the CAICOS version of the [Open Source drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver).